# how can i change the value inside collection laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i tried so hard to change the value inside collection and nothings was happen

here is my footage of datatable in html

[image]

i want to change that value of 0 and 1 into 'active' and 'non-active'

i tried change it on my function controller and didn't work

**controller.php**

```
public function reportView()
{

    $data = ReportViewAll::paginate(5);
    $reportviewall = $data->map(function($item, $key){
        $key = 'crewprogram_isdisabled';
        ($item = 0) ? $item = 'active' : $item = 'non-active';
        return $item;
    });

    return view('CrewProgram.ReportView.index', compact('reportviewall'));
}
```

how do i solve that?

and instead change it in function, can i change it in Eloquent model?

**Eloquent Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ReportViewAll extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv2';
    protected $table ='view_mastercrewprogram';
}
```

How can i solve this?

**EDIT**

this is my table, i tried some stuff up in my blade and still not working

**table.blade.php**

```
 <tbody>
    @foreach($reportviewall as $mastercrew)
    <tr>
        <td class="nik">{{$mastercrew->employee_nik}}</td>
        <td class="nik">{{$mastercrew->employee_nama}}</td>
        <td class="nik">{{$mastercrew->crewprogramposition_name}}</td>
        <td class="nik">{{$mastercrew->show_focus_id}}</td>
        <td class="nik">{{$mastercrew->show_name}}</td>
        <td class="nik">{{$mastercrew->crewprogrammemo_placement_id}}</td>
        <td class="nik">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($mastercrew->crewprogrammemo_placement_date)->format(' d-m-Y ')}}</td>
        <td class="nik">{{
          ($mastercrew->crewprogram_isdisabled = '0') ? $mastercrew->crewprogram_isdisabled = 'active' : $mastercrew->crewprogram_isdisabled = 'non-active'
        }}</td>
        <td class="nik">{{$mastercrew->crewprogrammemo_dismissal_id}}</td>
        <td class="nik">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($mastercrew->crewprogrammemo_dismissal_date)->format(' d-m-Y ')}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

Comment: What is the column name from the `view_mastercrewprogram` table contains the 0/1 (active/inactive) value?

Comment: Also could you edit your question to include the table blade/html code inside the `CrewProgram.ReportView.index` view.

Comment: @Purgatory i've edited and including my html in the code inside, i tried some stuff up using literator, and the values change, but all of them change into 'non-active'  , i want to make differentiate between 'non-active' as number 1 and 'active' as number 0

Comment: What is this syntax `($item = 0) ? $item = 'active' : $item = 'non-active';` . Not sure where you are getting that from. Just do `($item = 0) ? 'active' : 'non-active';` Although it would be ok if you just do that in the blade code.

Comment: i'm doing all pof that,, but i got all 'non-active'  (for value 1) even tough there is value 0 there @MarkSkayff

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo there. It'd be `($item == 0) ? $item = 'active' : $item = 'non-active';` The equal comparisson operator is `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I know you have solved your issue in your code by swapping the `=` for a correct comparison `==` so that you show `active`/`non-active` as asked. However, I would like to show you a few different ways of acheiving the same outcome but with better readability.

**Option 1: Zero is falsey**

I assume your `table.blade.php` field now looks like this:

```
<td class="nik">{{
    ($mastercrew->crewprogram_isdisabled == '0') ? $mastercrew->crewprogram_isdisabled = 'active' : $mastercrew->crewprogram_isdisabled = 'non-active'
}}</td>
```

This can be refactored to the below and you should get the same result.

```
<td class="nik">{{$mastercrew->crewprogram_isdisabled ? 'non-active' : 'active'}}</td>
```

Just as a reference the correct word is `inactive` when something is not active.

**Option 2: Add a mutator method to your model**

Laravel has lots of additional features you can do on your models to help when using them in your blade views. One of these is called `mutators` (see docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#introduction).

This basically lets you add additional fields to your models to prevent adding unnecessary logic to your blade views. *I recommend doing this if you plan to display `active`/`non-active` in other places as well.*

So you could add this function to your `ReporyViewAll`  model:

```
public function getActiveStatusAttribute() 
{
    return $this->crewprogram_isdisabled ? 'non-active' : 'active';   
}
```

Then in your `table.blade.php` you can change the field to this:

```
<td class="nik">{{$mastercrew->active_status}}</td>
```

Comment: what is that ```active_status```?? is that variable had been declared, or automatically be declared when using getActiveStatusAttribute?

Comment: The `getActiveStatusAttribute` function is automatically called when you do `$mastercrew->active_status`. The docs explain this well https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor please make use of them as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

to solve the problem its just use '==' instead '=', maybe i need to sleep